# Change the text of a label with a button in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Firstly, let me say I'm new to Swift and Xcode. I have a label that displays some text and I want that text to change when a button is pressed.

Here is the code in the UIViewController:

```
var txt = "Hey"

@IBOutlet weak var Text: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    showText()
}

func showText(){
    Text.text = txt
}

@IBAction func Button(_ sender: Any) {
    txt = "Hello"
}
```

The buttons and labels are correctly linked to their main.storyboard counterparts. When I run this and press the button the text doesn't change.

Comment: just call `showText()` inside your button IBAction. BTW it is Swift convention to name your vars, functions, IBOutlets and IBActions starting with a lowercase letter.

Comment: call `showText()` in `Button` after setting `txt`.  `viewDidLoad()` is only called one time when the ViewController is created.

Comment: Yep that worked!

Comment: sorry i didn't see that your problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code as per below

```
var txt = "Hey"

@IBOutlet weak var Text: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
showText()
}

func showText(){
Text.text = txt
}

@IBAction func Button(_ sender: UIButton) {
txt = "Hello"
showText()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`viewDidLoad()` is only called one time when the ViewController is created.  `showText()` needs to be called after `txt` is set if you want to display it.  One way to automate this is to add a property observer to `txt` to call `showText()` when `txt` is updated:

```
var txt = "Hey" {
    didSet {
        showText()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will add that it is more flexible and perhaps elegant to have your `showText()` method take the actual text to show as an **argument**, instead of depending on some **internal state** (the value of the property `txt: String`, that isn't immediately evident at the call site) to accomplish its task:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!

func showText(_ text: String){
    self.textLabelabel?.text = text

    // (optional chaining to avoid crash if accidentally 
    // called before viewDidLoad())
}  

@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    self.showText("Hello")  // From here it is clear what text will be shown
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Text of label with button just need to pass the text in label;

```
//Outlets  
@IBOutlet weak var firstLabel: UILabel!        
@IBOutlet weak var secondLabel: UILabel!


 //Button Action
 @IBAction func textChabge(_ sender: Any) {

            firstLabel.text = "newText"

            secondLabel.text = "newText"

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

just change your **IBAction** like this.

```
@IBAction func Button(_ sender: Any) {
    txt = "Hello"
    showText()
}
```