# Swift example not printing correct UILabel using UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uilabel

I am very new to Swift. I'm trying make a `UILabel` produce text when a `UIButton` is pressed. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46086381/change-the-text-of-a-label-with-a-button-in-ios) example on StackOverflow and have been trying to follow along, but instead of printing correctly it just changes the screen to blank. Why is this happening?

The desired result would be to have the `UILabel` say the enumerated strings. The console prints correctly what I am looking for in this case, but not the `UILabel`.

If this is a duplicate or I've missed something, kindly point me in the right direction and I will delete this post.

This is my code:

```
     import UIKit

        class ViewController: UIViewController {


        @IBOutlet weak var textDump: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var textButton: UIButton!

        var messageText = "Initial View"

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib

        }

        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(animated)
            view.backgroundColor = .black
            textDump.textColor = .white
            showText()
        }


        func showText(){
            textDump.text! = messageText
            textDump.textColor = .white
            print(textDump.text!)
        }

        @IBAction func buttonPress(_ sender: Any){
            var newText = ""
            for (n, c) in "Swift".enumerated(){
                newText = newText + "\n \(n): '\(c)' \n"
            }
            messageText = newText
            showText()
        }

}
```

Comment: What color is the label?

Comment: The label a black background with white text. The label appears correctly for the initial viewDidAppear method.

Comment: Ok. I saw you using white text and white text on a white background would not show. I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: Did you set number of lines to 0?

Comment: Hmm. I did not set any number of lines. Is the default 0? Bc that would be it then due to the new line.

Comment: Default is 1. Setting it to 0, means unlimited.

Comment: yep that was it.

Comment: Great! Good luck learning Swift. It's a lot of fun.

Comment: Much appreciated, Don!